# AZCopy between storage accounts and keep access rights

Tags: azure, azcopy

Suppose I do this operation between storage accounts:

AzCopy /Source:https://sourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer1 /Dest:https://destaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer2 /SourceKey:key1 /DestKey:key2 /Pattern:abc.txt

In mycontainer1 I have permission "Blob ..", but in mycontainer2 the permission becomes "Private ..." .  Is there a way to prevent this to happen / force the same permission on the "new" container?

Comment: Could you clarify clearer? What's your permission of source container? What's your permission of dest container? What do you want to prevent?

Comment: Source container:  Public access for blobs only  Destination container:  No public access for blobs.    I want destination container to get the same permission level as source container.

Answer (score 1):

AzCopy doesn't support this. It's designed for transferring blobs/files. You need to reconfigure the permission of your destination container by yourself.